# Transfer EOS failed using web3.py

Tags: tokens, web3.py

I want to use web3.py to send some EOS.
Here is my code:

```
from ethtoken.abi import EIP20_ABI
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

infura_provider = HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/CMI5Z7n7hAy8CP7nx95s')
w3 = Web3(infura_provider)
w3.eth.enable_unaudited_features()

contract_Address = w3.toChecksumAddress("0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0")
unicorns = w3.eth.contract(contract_Address, abi=EIP20_ABI)

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x030eC1E9E2AfA4A59a7C56F2B761505E1a414b45')

unicorn_txn = unicorns.functions.transfer(
    '0xFe0196504dF34c4Bf30D3089EfFf86cFe3B34617',
    1,
).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 1,
    'gas': 200000,
    'value': int(0.1 * (10 ** 18)),  # EOS:18 decimals
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('4', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce,
})

private_key = 'my private key'
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(unicorn_txn, private_key=private_key)

TxHash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(TxHash.hex())
```

The code runs without error and print out the TxHash,but the transaction failed,the specific reason can be found here:[transaction information](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9b2fad048600d8b0e809e397a0df4681235061501f31a42cc20a50cbee661dd6)

I don't know how to fix this,can anyone help me?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
the value should be 0,since I want to transfer token,not eth.

```
unicorn_txn = unicorns.functions.transfer(
'0xFe0196504dF34c4Bf30D3089EfFf86cFe3B34617',
1,
).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 1,
    'gas': 200000,
    'value': 0
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('4', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce,
})
```